# Any annotation available to cluster Oracle WLS EJB?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

As said in the title, I'd like to know if there's a proprietary Oracle WLS annotation which specifies that an EJB is going to be clustered. Basically the equicalent of adding this to your weblogic-ejb-jar.xml:

```
<stateless-clustering>
   <stateless-bean-is-clusterable>True
   </stateless-bean-is-clusterable>
   <stateless-bean-load-algorithm>random
   </stateless-bean-load-algorithm>
</stateless-clustering>
```

Thanks!
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuration such as bean pool size and clustering are not exposed through annotations. They can be only specified through deployment descriptor.

To see a list of WLS 12c EJB proprietary annotations, please see [WebLogic EJB Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/annotations.htm#i1438312)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well my only doubt about your statement is about bean pool size which I'd bet I have seen time ago a WLS annotation for specifying the pool size. Unfortunately I cannot make up my mind where I've found it :-(

Comment: @MaxKorn, you can check out link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24977/summary.htm. There is a table there regarding configuration in deployment descriptor vs annotation. As you can see, the corresponding annotations for initial-beans-in-free-pool and max-beans-in-free-pool are N/A.